# Azure load testing from multiple regions

Tags: azure

Is this possible to configure the Azure load test from multiple regions? The application is deployed on EASTUS location but the users access this application from Europe and US both. I want to put the load on this application from both locations at the same time. Is this possible with Azure load test tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of today Azure Load Test cannot do that (it might be added later as a feature).

We have built something like that, a geo-distributed load testing rig based on Azure Container Instances in various Azure regions. However, it uses Locust instead of JMeter. Take a look if you are interested: https://github.com/Azure/Mission-Critical-Online/tree/main/src/testing/loadtest-locust